# Как спрятать появляющийся от Google API "микрофончик"?

Tags: java, android, распознавание-речи

Брал [отсюда](http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-how-to-implement-voice-recognition-a-nice-easy-tutorial/) пример для работы с голосом. Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы появляющийся от Google API "микрофончик" не был виден (нажимаешь на кнопку, говоришь и получаешь результат сказанного, без этой графической визуализации).

Comment: Ответ в [продолжении](http://hashcode.ru/questions/48813/%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8-voice-recognition-part-2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/48813/%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8-voice-recognition-part-2).

Answer (score 1):

Можно не вызывать `Voice Recognition Activity`, а взять исходный код этой активности и перенести в свой проект, тогда у вас появится возможность по своему усмотрению встраивать UI в свое приложение. Как это делается, можно посмотреть в исходном коде для `LatinIME` (папка voice) - там 7 файлов и больше 1000 строк кода под лицензией Apache.

Answer (score 1):

Есть другой способ:

- Получаем "сырые" данные с микрофона с помощью класса AudioRecord (описание,
     например, [тут](http://findevelop.blogspot.com/2011/06/android.html))
- Кодируем данные в формат flac с помощью [JavaFlacEncoder](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaflacencoder/)
- Отправляем файл на
     https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?xjerr=1&client=chromium&lang=ru-RU
     с content-type: "audio/x-flac; rate=16000"
- Получаем json-ответ с вариантами текста.