# Распознавание речи (voice recognition). part 2

Tags: java, android, распознавание-речи

Вообщем, я сделал, то, что спрашивал в [предыдущем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/47060/%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8-voice-recognition) вопросе.

```
public class VoiceActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private TextView mText;
private SpeechRecognizer sr;
private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
public String str;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.speakButton);
    mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    sr = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    sr.setRecognitionListener(new listener());
}

class listener implements RecognitionListener {
    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReadyForSpeech");
    }

    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBeginningOfSpeech");
    }

    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRmsChanged");
    }

    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBufferReceived");
    }

    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onEndofSpeech");
    }

    public void onError(int error) {
        Log.d(TAG, "error " + error);
        mText.setText("error " + error);
    }

    public void onResults(Bundle results) {
        str = new String();
        Log.d(TAG, "onResults " + results);
        ArrayList<String> data = results
                .getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            Log.d(TAG, "result " + data.get(i));
            str += data.get(i);
        }
        mText.setText("results: " + str);
    }

    public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPartialResults");
    }

    public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onEvent " + eventType);
    }
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.speakButton) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, "com.moc");
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
        sr.startListening(intent);
    }
}
}
```

Интересует следующий вопрос: **каким образом правильно сделать пересылку полученный строки в другой Activity, без вывода в TextViev?**

---

*Update:*  А вот как сделать автоматический переход в другое активити после определения голоса (нажимаешь - говоришь - открывает след. активити и в нем результат)? Просто, если как у меня в примере, то он пишет ошибку в строке intent.setClass(this, SecondActivity.class);

---

Была мысль:

```
public void onResults(Bundle results) {
        str = new String();
        Log.d(TAG, "onResults " + results);
        ArrayList<String> data = results
                .getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            Log.d(TAG, "result " + data.get(i));
            str += data.get(i);
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("StrID", str);
            intent.putExtras(b);
        intent.setClass(this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

но она крайне неправильная.

Comment: Ответ по Update: intent.setClass(VoiceActivity.this, SecondActivity.class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну я бы не сказал, что мысль с интентом неправильная - extras ведь как раз и предназначены для передачи данных между активити.

Только я бы немного сократил ваш код вызова активити, вот так:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtras("StrID", str);
startActivity(intent);
```

Но это в случае, если строка вам нужна только в SecondActivity. Если она понадобится потом еще в какой-то активити, то пересылать её туда-сюда будет нудно.

На этот случай можно создать свой класс приложения ([документация](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)):

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    public String recognizedString; //объявлена public для примера, можно сделать private и геттеры/сеттеры для неё
}
```

Доступ к экземпляру приложения можно получить из любой активити.

В VoiceActivity:

```
...
MyApp app = (MyApp) getApplication();
app.recognizedString = str;
...
```

В SecondActivity:

```
...
MyApp app = (MyApp) getApplication();
String recStr = app.recognizedString;
...
```

Comment: Спасибо, про пересылку очень понятно и подробно.